# Filter "Only students"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

It would be nice, if I can see only students. Because we opening some position for summer internship for University students.

Comment: Looks like this was recently implemented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a request for a new flag on user profiles.  Perhaps this is another use for the "Careers" section?  After all, they have the discounted rate for students there, so presumably they'd already be flagged (and seeking opportunities, to boot!).

Answer (score 2):

If you're offering an internship, why not simply select "Internship or Co-op" when you search? Why limit yourself to students? It's also worth noting that some students may have taken advantage of the $29/3 year deal and aren't considered "students" by the system.